# Subview common to multiple view controllers is unresponsive

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uiviewcontroller, uiview-hierarchy

I am using a `UIView` to show busy/processing clue to User and components in loading view are not responding to user touches. Let me elaborate my problem.
I have around 3 `UIViewController`s and based on situation one `View` from `VieControllers` would be displayed. I use following code to change current view

```
UIView *currentView = self.view;
UIView *theWindow = [currentView superview];

//Some other code 

[currentView removeFromSuperview];
[self.view setFrame: [tileCountViewController.view bounds]];
[theWindow addSubview:tileCountViewController.view];
[theWindow setFrame:[tileCountViewController.view bounds]];
[theWindow setFrame: [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
```

I then have a Loading view which generally used to show busy/processing kinda of UI to User. I created Loading view in following way from nib file

```
- (id)init {

    UIDeviceOrientation orientation = [UIDevice currentDevice].orientation;
    NSString *nibName = @"LoadingViewController";
    if(UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(orientation)) {
        nibName = @"LoadingView-landscape";
    }
    else {
        nibName = @"LoadingView";
    }

    UINib *nib = [UINib nibWithNibName:nibName bundle:nil];
    UIView *portraitView = [[nib instantiateWithOwner:self options:nil] objectAtIndex:0];
    self = [super initWithFrame:portraitView.frame];

    [self addSubview:portraitView];
    [self bringSubviewToFront:portraitView];
    return self;

}
```

In app delegate, I initialize loading view and add it to Main window

```
if(!loadingViewIndicator){
    loadingViewIndicator = [[LoadingView alloc]init];
}
[[[UIApplication sharedApplication]keyWindow]addSubview:loadingViewIndicator];
loadingViewIndicator.hidden = YES;
```

Whenever I need to show loading/busy view, I simply load it like this

```
[loadingViewIndicator performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(startLoadingViewIndicator:) withObject:startMsg waitUntilDone:NO];
- (void)startLoadingViewIndicator:(NSString *)startMsg{
    self.hidden = NO;
    [self.superview bringSubviewToFront:self];
    [self.activityIndicator startAnimating];
    [self.loadingMessage setText:startMsg];
    self.loadingProgressView.progress = 0.0f;

    [self refreshPosition];
}
```

Everything works fine but components in Loading view are not responding to touches. Any clue what is going wrong?

I just realized that problem is due to threading issue. I show this subview when User starts downloading any file. My earlier code was to directly start download

```
urlconnection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self startImmediately: YES];
```

I am now calling this method from another method using background thread as below

```
[self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(startDownload) withObject:nil];
```

And then I am adding runloop in download like

```
urlconnection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self startImmediately: YES];
CFRunLoopRun();
```

This works fine and my subview is responsive. It really took lots of time. The problem is there is clear code example to help to run download in background thread and at the same time make UI responsive.

Comment: try `[loadingView setUserInteractionEnabled:TRUE];`

Comment: @George Its already done in Nib fine. I still tried in code but no success.